# How to specify functionalities to different user roles?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have a management system, where users can register and manage the system following CRUD. I would like the admin to be the only one that can add, update and delete other users. If the user role is not admin, only the Search function should work. However, this is how the currentAccount (active user) is stored in sessionStorage:

`{id: 1, password: "111111", type: "0", userName: "admin"}`

It does not include the role of the user as shown here:

`(user.type === "0" ? "Normal User" : "Administrator")`
I am using the above line to show the role of the user in the browser.
This user is initially implemented in Java as follows:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String type;
    ----------
    ----------
    ----------
    ----------
}
```

My add function looks like this:

```
function addUser() {
   popWindow("add_user.html", "add user");
}
```

My delete function looks like this:

```
function deleteUser(id) {
      let form = document.querySelector("#queryForm");
      let formData = new FormData(form);
      formData.append("action", DELETE);
      formData.append("ids", id);
      sendPost("/SMS/user", formData2Url(formData), handleDelete);
}


function handleDelete() {
      search();
}

function search() {
      let form = document.querySelector("#queryForm");
      let formData = new FormData(form);
      formData.append("action", QUERY);
      sendPost("/SMS/user", formData2Url(formData), handleQuery);
}
```

My update function looks like this:

```
function updateUser(user) {
   sessionStorage.setItem("user2Delete", JSON.stringify(user));
   popWindow("update_user.html", "update user");
}
```

The idea that I have is to check through a list of `users`, look for the user that is in the `currentAccount` object, then get the `type` of that user. However, it doesn't seem to work. IS there a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Decorators. Its like wrapping your function in another. With decorators you can check if the user is an admin, yes? Then execute the function, No? Do nothing. Like you have a class and want some of the properties readonly

```
class Oatmeal extends Porridge {
  @readOnly viscosity = 20;
  // (you can also put @readOnly on the line above the property)

  constructor(flavor) {
    super();
    this.flavor = flavor;
  }
}
```

and the decorator @readonly would look like

```
function readOnly(target, key, descriptor) {
  return {
    ...descriptor,
    writable: false,
  };
}
```

Have a look here. It‘s agood explanation about Decorators https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-javascript-decorators/